# How to force my nav and button to mantain a constant height?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
    
            /*header*/
            .header {
                
                padding: 2.5vw;
                position: relative;
                background: linear-gradient(to right, #EE7752 25%, #E73C7E 50%, #23A6D5 75%, #23D5AB 100%);
                background-size: 200% 200%;
                animation: Gradiente 15s ease infinite;
                font-size:15px;
            }
    
            @keyframes Gradiente {
                0% {
                    background-position: 0% 50%
                }
    
                50% {
                    background-position: 100% 50%
                }
    
                100% {
                    background-position: 0% 50%
                }
            }
    
            .header p {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                margin-right: -50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
            }
    
            /*navbar*/
            .flex {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                width: 100%;
                
            }
    
            .option {
                display: flex;
                width: 24.7%;
                color: white;
                background-color: grey;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                height: 4vw;
                margin-left:0.25vw;
    
            }
            #menu{
                display:none;
            }
    
            
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <section class="container1">
            <div class="header">
                <h1><p>Examen B 2DAW</p></h1>
            </div>
    
            <nav>
                <div class="flex">
                    <div id="menu">Menú</div>
                    <div class="option"><a href="#"></a>Opcion 1</div>
                    <div class="option"><a href="#"></a>Opcion 2</div>
                    <div class="option"><a href="#"></a>Opcion 3</div>
                    <div class="option"><a href="#"></a>Opcion 4</div>
                </div>
            </nav>
    
        </section>
 
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Which when shrinking is decreasing its height, which is something I dont want to happen, since I want it to mantain a constant height

This is how mine looks shrinked

[image: Mine is shrinked]

But its supposed to look like this (mantaining its height), I have tried setting heights with px, and vw, but it didnt make a difference. Ive tried to use different font sizes but i cant solve this. I need it to maintain its height, while getting horizontally smaller, why isnt it happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you class `header` and `nav` just set a `min-height`

Example:

```
min-height:60px;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that your padding is set to viewport width (vw), which will change in value accordingly. If you want the height to be static, use px for the padding OR the height. If you want, you can use height and padding together, but keep in mind that the two will add up.

```
        .header {
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
            position: relative;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #EE7752 25%, #E73C7E 50%, #23A6D5 75%, #23D5AB 100%);
            background-size: 200% 200%;
            animation: Gradiente 15s ease infinite;
            font-size: 15px;
        }
```

OR

```
        .header {
            height: 40px;
            position: relative;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #EE7752 25%, #E73C7E 50%, #23A6D5 75%, #23D5AB 100%);
            background-size: 200% 200%;
            animation: Gradiente 15s ease infinite;
            font-size: 15px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give padding: 50px; in header class and padding-top: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px; in option class. I hope it will fulfill your requirement.